# Install two versions of mono? Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, mono, ubuntu-16.04, monodevelop

I need to run two different versions of mono at the same time for two separate applications on ubuntu 16.04. is this possible? How can I go about doing this?

Comment: It is highly recommended that you use Docker or VirtualBox to virtuallize, but you do have an option called parallel Mono, http://www.mono-project.com/docs/compiling-mono/parallel-mono-environments/

Comment: Thank you Lex Li, didnt even think about using docker! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So expand my comment above as it turns out to be useful.

**Virtualization**
You really should use a virtualization technologies to build Mono environments, so

- Hypervisors such as VirtualBox should give you heavy environments with chosen OS.
- Container based solutions such as Docker should give you light environments according to the images you choose.

**Parallel Mono**
This is a very special setup Mono team used to document when developers have a default Mono installation from the Linux official repo, while would like to also build Mono from source code for experiments.

[The steps were documented in an article.](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/compiling-mono/parallel-mono-environments/)

My personal suggestion is that you go the virtualized ways, and most should use Docker today.